# c# creating many new objects what happens to memory

Tags: c#, memory-management, static, garbage-collection

I have multiple threads that have to access static objects. The main thread holds this static object and a database thread handles changes on a data table that holds information about this object.
Every time the database table changes, I wait on a mutex and change the underlying properties in the database thread.
Now I have implemented a static method in the main thread that gets a deep copy of the object, so that other threads cannot change the properties of this object. The static method does nothing else as creating a new object and copying the property information from the current object.
So every time another thread needs to access this object, another new object is created. 
My question is, is this in anyway a bad practice, because memory is always rising before the gc arrives?
Are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from memory drawbacks, the new objects might not be up-to-date during their lifetime (unless you keep a reference to all of them and update all of them in you DB thread).

If I understood, you want to have an object which could be modified by a unique client (your DB thread) but remains read-only to other actors. You can use a read-only interface as a contract for your object, and make other threads access the object only through it interface

```
public interface IObject
{
    string Field1 { get; }
    string Field3 { get; }
    string Field2 { get; }
}

class RealObject : IObject
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
    public string Field3 { get; set; }
}

class DBClass
{
    private RealObject _object;

    public IObject GetObject()
    {
        return _object;
    }

    ...
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This sounds good! What about something like an data changed event in the database thread. Every other thread registers for this event and so get notified if something is changed.

Comment: It's possible yes, bet perhaps it's better to do it directly on the object (i.e by implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface), it depends if you want to notify on each field change or after each full DB<->object update